# How to check if an Image Transform exists?

Tags: image-transforms

Is there an elegant way to check if an image transform exists?

```
{% if craft.imageTransformExists('thumb') %}
  <img src="{{asset.getUrl(thumb)}}" alt="Image">
{% else %}
  This image transform doesn't exists, please create it
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Brad says, you'd need to write a custom plugin – specifically, one that provides a [Template Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) class exposing the AssetTransformsService's [`getTransformByHandle`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetTransformsService#getTransformByHandle-detail) method.

The variable class could look something like this:

```
class MyPluginVariable
{

    public function imageTransformExists($handle)
    {
        // Returns null if transform doesn't exist
        return craft()->assetTransforms->getTransformByHandle($handle);
    }

}
```

Then, you'd be able to test for named image transforms in your templates like this:

```
{% if craft.myPlugin.imageTransformExists('thumb') %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

If you're not familiar with plugin development, it might be useful to use the [Business Logic plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) as a starting point – it even has a Variable class which you could just drop the above `imageTransformExists` method into.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer 'mmikkel'. Looking into it a little further, it does make sense as to why there isn't a native template-side method for this. As Brad mentions, there are fallbacks already in place. Fortunately for me, this is still going to be of use as I plan to dynamically create this image transform onAfterInstall() on the condition it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing native, but it could probably be pulled off with a custom [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction).

But just to be clear, if a transform currently doesn't exist then Craft will automatically create it on that request, so the code you shared is pretty much already happening behind the scene.